# css `<tag>:has(+ <tag>)` is not applied

Tags: html, css, styles

Here is the intended behavior:

For each element with a class `.inline-s-collapsible` of which the previous element is a p tag, apply the styling to the p tag.

And here is my code:

```
p:has(+ .inline-s-collapsible) {
    display: inline-block !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Why isn't it working?

https://jsfiddle.net/e6dxzo5g/

It should work: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

Comment: `has` has no support actually https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: No browser will interpret `:has`, it's not implemented yet.

Comment: it's not implemented in any browser

Comment: Oh, I see, do you know of an alternative to the css shown in the question?